# Stopped working

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Is there another way to say *stopped working* in the following sentences:

> 1. My computer stopped working (but if I say "broke down" doesn't it mean that the computer is *broken*)

> 2. The internet connection stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways, many of which are a little casual.

> The computer has crashed.

> The computer froze.

> Something has hung my computer.

Or with the internet

> The internet is down.

Answer (score -1):

> My computer stopped working.

The alternative you can use it:

> My computer broke down.

**break down** - of a machine, to malfunction or break altogether. [Source](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/broke+down)

**break down** - Something that is broken-down does not now work or is in bad condition. [Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/broken-down)

As stated in these meanings, break down can indicate either cases, you computer or monitor has stopped working or it has broken altogether (parts breaking off).

However, if you want to signify that your computer has broke down into its constituent parts, you might consider using the word [disintegrate](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/disintegrate?s=ts).

As for your second sentence, using it is alright. [As the title of this article states](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20170207-what-if-the-internet-stopped-for-a-day), it is very much common to use it. Though if you are looking for a more sophisticated word, you may consider saying:

> The internet connection is/got disrupted.

**disrupt** - to break apart. [Source](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/disrupt)

Comment: We would normally use 'break down" about something mechanical, that has moving parts such as gears, wheels, etc, like a car, in short, a machine. A computer has no moving parts, except maybe a cooling fan.

Comment: But this statement is too commonly heard everywhere nowadays, at least I have heard it many a times.